# Current Balance after payment

Tags: sql

My table

```
buysell payment_date    balance     amount_paid 
175325  2023-07-01      1000.00     NULL             
175325  2023-07-02      0.00        500.00           
175325  2023-07-03      0.00        400.00           
175325  2023-07-04      0.00        100.00
```

Expect result

```
payment_date    balance  amount_paid    current_balance
2023-07-01      1000.00  NULL           1000.00
2023-07-02      0.00     500.00         500.00
2023-07-03      0.00     400.00         100.00
2023-07-04      0.00     100.00         0.00
```

My query

```
;with ctec as
( 
    select payment_date, balance, amount_paid,
    sum(amount_paid) over (order by payment_date) as running_total
    from  AG
) 

select  payment_date, balance, amount_paid, 
        balance - coalesce(running_total, 0) as current_balance
from
    ctec
    group by  payment_date, balance, amount_paid, running_total
order by
    payment_date
```

This query give the result incorrect.

BUT if I replace  
balance - coalesce(running_total, 0) as current_balance 
to 
1000 - coalesce(running_total, 0) as current_balance 
Then I got right result

However, I need value from Balance field NOT the number because I have no way to know the Balance number for all records. I do not know why the Balance value does not work. Need you help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you just replace `balance` with `first_value(balance) over (order by payment_date)` in your query?

Comment: Oh yes, look like it's working. I still puzzle by this. If you can explain more then great. Other wise your excellent work

Comment: It works because it's taking 1000 as the first balance. As you had it, you are taking 0 as the balance (except for the first row).

Comment: Yup @Isolated is right on the money

Comment: How do I give you guys credit, I do not see green check mark for done.

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan could add that as an answer, then you can give credit.

Comment: Oh yup I will right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `balance` with `first_value(balance) over (order by payment_date)`.

As @Isolated mentioned in the OP comments this works because:

> It works because it's taking 1000 as the first balance. As you had it, you are taking 0 as the balance (except for the first row).